# How to display comma delimited JSON value as a list?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, html-lists

Say I have an array like this:

```
    var ARTISTS: Artist[] = [
      {
         "name": "Barot Bellingham",
         "shortname": "Barot_Bellingham",
         "reknown": "Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
         "bio": "Some bio here...",
         "friends": "James, Harry, Bob"
      }
```

Is it possible to display values for the key “friends” as an unordered list where each friend would be it’s own list item, e.g.:

```
    <ul>
      <li>James</li>
      <li>Harry</li>
      <li>Bob</li>
    </ul>
```

I do realize the "friends" would be better stored as a nested array in order to display as a list, but I'm looking into this as a potential workaround for another issue.

Thank you!

P.S. I'm using Angular 2.

Comment: grab your artist's friends field and call split(',') on it.

`ARTISTS[0].friends.split(',')` will give you `[ 'James', ' Harry', ' Bob' ]`

Comment: `split(', ')` would trim the whitespace at the same time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get an array of friends.

```
var arrayOfFriends = Artist[0].friends.split(", ");
// arrayOfFriends = ['James', 'Harry', 'Bob']
```

From there loop over the array and create your list

Comment: Actually you get `['James', ' Harry', ' Bob']`

Comment: Thanks! This helps, but I don't think I'm out of the woods just yet.

When "friends" is an array (i.e. pre .split(', ')), I displayed them like this:

`<li *ngFor="let friend of artist.friends">{{friend}}</li>`

If I use `<script>var arrayOfFriends = Artist[0].friends.split(", ");</script>` how do I then go about display them as a list?